# Difference between frames and complete sequence

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a separable Hilbert space with inner product $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle$.

A sequence $\left\{f_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ of elements in $\mathcal{H}$ is a frame for $\mathcal{H}$ if there exist constants $A, B>0$ such that
$$
A\|f\|^2 \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|\left\langle f, f_k\right\rangle\right|^2 \leq B\|f\|^2, \quad \forall f \in \mathcal{H} .
$$
It follows from this definition that if $\left\{f_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a frame for $\mathcal{H}$, then
$$
\overline{\operatorname{span}}\left\{f_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}=\mathcal{H} .
$$
i.e. the sequence $\left\{f_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is complete. Is the converse still true? What is a sequence that is complete but it is not a frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $f_n = \frac{1}{n}e_n$, where $e_n \in \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ is the $n$-th standard basis vector. It is easy to see that this is complete but not a frame (do it!).

Comment: Hi PhoemueX, thank you! I tried to do some steps and I obtained that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|\left\langle f, f_k\right\rangle\right|^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{|c_k|^2}{k^2}$ where $c_k$ is the k-th component of $f$ with respect to $e_k$. But $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{|c_k|^2}{k^2}\leq ||f||$ and $B=1$ whereas we can't find a number $A$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{|c_k|^2}{k^2}\geq A||f||$. Am I right?

Comment: @Mark: Yes. You need to consider $\|f\|^2$ (note the square) everywhere. To show that no positive $A$ exists, you can use $f = e_m$ and let $m \to \infty$.

Comment: Great, thank you again. How can I prove that $\overline{\mathrm{span}\lbrace f_k \rbrace_{n=1}^\infty} = \ell^2$? I have to prove that every $f$ is $=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k e_k/k$ and if $f=(p_1,p_2,\dots)$ we have that $\alpha_1=p_1$, $\alpha_2=2p_2$ ... $\alpha_n=n p_n$ and so on. Thus I proved that $\overline{\mathrm{span}\lbrace f_k \rbrace_{n=1}^\infty} $ spans $\ell^2$. Right?

Comment: I would first show that the span of the $f_n$ is the same as the span of the $e_n$. It is well-known that the span of an orthonormal basis is dense.